# NHibernate save object in one-to-one relationship

Tags: nhibernate, save, relationship, one-to-one

I'm a new in nHibernate help me to save an object and his connections in the base.
I've got the base with two tables:

- person (idPerson, firstName, secondName, idService
- service (idService, name)

The table service has 3 positions (gold, silver, brilliant)

---

The Mapping:

```
 public class PersonMap:ClassMap<Person>
    {
        public PersonMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.id);
            Map(x => x.firstName);
            Map(x => x.lastName);
            Map(x => x.status);
            References(x => x.serviceType).Column("idServiceType");
            Table("Person");
        }
    }
    public class ServiceMap : ClassMap<ServiceType>
    {
        public ServiceMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.id);
            Map(x => x.serviceName);
            Table("Service");
        }
    }
```

I use the next method in Repository for saving:

```
public void Saves(Person entity)
    {
        using (var session = hibernateHelp.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                ServiceRepository srp = new ServiceRepository();
                NHibernateUtil.Initialize(entity.service);
                session.Save(entity);
                transaction.Commit();
            }

        }
    }
```

I recive the date (firstName="My" lastName="Go" status=TRUE, serviceType="gold"), then I create a Person:

```
Person df=new Person{
           firstName="My",
           lastName="Go",
           status=true,
           serviceType=new ServiceType{serviceName="gold"}
           };
```

When I send it to the Repository method Save(see above) the mapping is working and saving the new object in the table person and create the new note in the table service. 
I need't to create the new note in the table service since it containts one. How to make the saver's method in order to save the link to the table server, but not create the new one???
I appreciate any links and suggestions.

Comment: Could you still post you mapping for Person and SerciveType.

Answer (score 0):

```
Person newPerson = new Person
{
    FirstName = "My",
    LastName = "Go",
    Status = true,
    serviceType = session.Load<ServiceType>(idOfGold)  // returns the service if loaded or a proxy representing it which is enough to save the reference
    // or
    serviceType = session.Query<ServiceType>().Where(st.name == "gold").Single()
};

session.Save(newPerson);
```

Comment: Thank's a lot @Firo, this will work if I create Person in the Save method. Actually I use MVC and as Responce I recieve (firstName="My", LastName="Go", Status=TRUE, serviceType="gold") then I wont to create the Person object and send it to the method Save(Person entity) in my Repository. Any thought how it can be done?

Comment: just replace `session.Query<ServiceType>` with `ServiceTypeRepository.GetAll()` and the `session.Save()` with `PersonRepository.Save()`. btw i don't like repositories see here for reasons: http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton

Comment: sidenote: it would be a good idea to stick with .NET naming conventions and use PascalCase for Properties as seen in my answer